# Question from HNQ widget on Android doesn't load, showing last viewed question instead

Tags: bug, android-app, hot-questions, android-app-widgets

I have found myself in an uncomfortable situation after clicking the Hot Network Question widget.

I click the widget, it opens Stack Exchange app and doesn't refresh. That causes me seeing the question I haven been reading a while ago. Fact is that I haven't killed the app since using it last time.

Is there any known workaround to prevent this bug occurring every time I want to read a question opened from a widget? Killing the app/deleting data every time is not a convenient option.

It happens on all Android devices, so device specs aren't relevant, I guess.

Edit: it isn't reproducible 100% of the time. Sometimes it works.

Comment: repro'd, if it wasn't obvious already

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.83, though I only left the app for 10 seconds and tapping the question on HNQ (*will try for longer duration*). Meanwhile, please mention all Android devices that are affected, their Android version and the SE app version.

Comment: Could reproduce on Nexus 6, 6.0.1, and Galaxy S3 stock KitKat. SE version 1.0.83

Comment: Guess it's related to my own issue, that opening the app via notification sometimes opens the last viewed question, or the feed, and not the inbox. The android app developer (Kasra) wasn't able to reproduce it, so I fear there won't be any fix.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh yes! That is the exact same behaviour. Maybe they will be able to fix your issue after they reproduce this.

Comment: Need to find a way to reproduce it myself first, android app got one single developer, who already looked into it, and won't do it again unless I can tell him "Here, this is how to reproduce".

Comment: Okay, I'll try to find a reliable way of reproducing this issue, too.

Comment: Well, while trying to reproduce that, I have encountered a similar related glitch. 
I have opened my Achievements page, lost focus on app and opened another question from the HNQ widget. 

https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/zt1lUWjlK6cwlfk3es7nHj6psvsbLGFy/Screenshot_20160302-171139.png

After discussing this with a fellow Android developer, he said something like "Yeah, layout overlapping, nothing unusual". 
I guess I will contact mr Kasra in order to get this fixed.

Comment: Sir, as discussed above, it's reproducible on multiple devices and I guess Google won't help me at all since it's a problem in the app itself, not the system. Btw, just reproduced it while opening it from notifications @ShadowWizard

Comment: Awesome, there is an active chat room for the app: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/705/ios-and-android-apps I have already posted what you said, you can also join and if needed explain further how to reproduce. :)

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you have an Internet connection and the device that has enough storage to run the application or that might be slowing the app down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't help at all though. I have a working Internet connection and storage of 10 GB free and RAM about 1 GB free.  As I stated before, it affects every device, so mine is not the cause.

Comment: It might be just the system software try restarting the device turn it back on and wait for a few minutes then go back to it and try again and if that still doesn't help then it might be something internally in the hard drive but if that happens please contact services that you got the device from and they maybe able to help you with your concern. Thank you.. DJay-Rus

Comment: Sir, as discussed above, it's reproducible on multiple devices and I guess Google won't help me at all since it's a problem in the app itself, not the system.

Comment: Well If it is the app itself, then google might be able to help if you send a report on it to google. DJAY-RUS

Comment: Why would I report it to Google? I think Google doesn't care unless there were a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: Report the problem to the company that owns the app.